# Как сравнить время в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, время

Здравствуйте!

Решил ознакомиться с python'ом, и не могу понять как сравнить время. 
В переменную получаем время в формате MM:SS от 00:00 до 90:00, нужно собирать только  тогда, когда время меньше либо равно 59:00 (59 минут), потом выполнять условие.
Как это можно сделать?

---

Дополнительная информация: Я вырезал лишнее, чтобы было видно что код работает, так как полный код нерабочий. Не знаю как сделать проверку, чтобы собирал только те ссылки, которые имеют время меньше 59:00

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError

URL_BASE = 'https://1xbet.kz/'
URL = 'https://1xbet.kz/live/Football/'
ITEM_PATH = '.game_content_line .dashboard .c-events__item .c-events__item'
SECOND_PATH = '.db-stats__bottom-table .db-stats-table__group'

def parse_bets():
    f = urlopen(URL)
    list_html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)

    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH):
        span = elem.cssselect('span')[0]
        timer = span.text
        #можно ли здесь сделать проверку времени?
        #кажется время и ссылки не взаимосвязаны
        a = elem.cssselect('a')[0]
        href = a.get('href')
        url = urljoin(URL_BASE, href)
        bets = {'time': timer, 'url': url}
        #в итоге здесь они отображаются неправильно
        print(bets)


def main():
    parse_bets()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так: ?

```
def check(stime):
  minutes, seconds = stime.split(':')
  seconds = int(seconds) + (int(minutes) * 60)
  return seconds <= (59 * 60)


#using
print(check('9:00'))
print(check('59:00'))
print(check('59:01'))
print(check('109:00'))
```

P.S: Исправлена проблема о которой говорит @jfs

---

?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError

URL_BASE = 'https://1xbet.kz/'
URL = 'https://1xbet.kz/live/Football/'
ITEM_PATH = '.game_content_line .dashboard .c-events__item .c-events__item'
SECOND_PATH = '.db-stats__bottom-table .db-stats-table__group'


def check_time(stime):
  minutes, seconds = stime.split(':')
  seconds = int(seconds) + (int(minutes) * 60)
  return seconds <= (59 * 60)


def parse_bets():
    f = urlopen(URL)
    list_html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)

    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH):
        span = elem.cssselect('span')[0]
        timer = span.text
        if (not timer) or (not check_time(timer)):
            continue


        a = elem.cssselect('a')[0]
        href = a.get('href')
        url = urljoin(URL_BASE, href)
        bets = {'time': timer, 'url': url}
        #в итоге здесь они отображаются неправильно
        print(bets)


def main():
    parse_bets()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У вас где-то в коде  есть строка "st = None", а после неё не отрабатывает строка "st = строка". Можете удалить строку "st = None", и возможно тогда причина ошибки станет ясней

Comment: Ну или киньте код в котором используете решение, я попробую найти проблему

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!) дальше постараюсь сам всё сделать

Comment: можете помочь? не могу разобраться как взять данные с div'a если они "обрамлены" скриптами, вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702634/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-div-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pythone)