# Не получается получить данные из div парсером на python'e

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить цифры 86 и 82 из следующего кода:

```
<div class="db-stats-table__group">
<div class="db-stats-table__count">
    <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
    86
    <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
</div>
<div class="db-stats-table__description">Атаки</div>
<div class="db-stats-table__count">
    <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
    82
    <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
</div>
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
def parse_site():
    f = urlopen(URL)
    list_html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)

    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH):
        lidev = elem.cssselect('div')[0, 2]
        lidiv = lidev.text
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import bs4

example="""<div class="db-stats-table__group">
<div class="db-stats-table__count">
    <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
    86
    <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
</div>
<div class="db-stats-table__description">Атаки</div>
<div class="db-stats-table__count">
    <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
    82
    <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
</div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(example,"lxml")
for p in soup.find_all("div", class_="db-stats-table__count"):
    data_out = (p.get_text()).strip()
    print(data_out)
```

Comment: спасибо, ваш код работает, но когда я его внедряю в свой выходит ошибка после этой строчки: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(example,"lxml")` сам тип ошибки: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: попытался исправить ошибки, в итоге парсер запускается, но ничего не выдаёт, код могу прикрепить к вопросу